# python object attributes and methods

Tags: python

In python all data is object and any object should have attributes and methods.
Does somebody know python object without any attributes and methods?

```
>>> len(dir(1))
64
```

Comment: yes just try it in python 2.7

Comment: Guys sorry, I tried it in Pycharm, it returns nothing, but when I tried it in IDLE, it returned a list of attributes and methods

Answer (score 2):

This is easy to accomplish by [overriding `__dir__`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#dir) and `__getattribute__`:

```
class Empty(object):
    def __dir__(self):
        return []
    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        raise AttributeError("'{0}' object has no attribute '{1}'".format(type(self).__name__, name))

e = Empty()
dir(e)
[]
e.__name__
AttributeError: 'Empty' object has no attribute '__name__'
```

(In [python2](/questions/tagged/python2), `Empty` needs to be a new-style class, so the `class Empty(object):` is required; in [python3](/questions/tagged/python3) old-style classes are extinct so `class Empty:` is sufficient.)

Comment: `dir(x)` returning empty list doesn't means `x` has no attributes/methods.

Comment: @PauloScardine you can override `__getattribute__` as well.

Comment: `e.__class__` results `__main__.Empty` even with your tricks.

Comment: @PauloScardine which version? http://ideone.com/pcFfp `AttributeError: 'Empty' object has no attribute '__class__'` on everything I've tried.

Comment: `Python 2.7.2 (default, Jun 12 2011, 14:24:46) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]`

Comment: @PauloScardine http://ideone.com/smVQh (have you forgotten to make it a new-style class?)

Comment: @PauloScardine right, for Python2 you need to change it to `class Empty(object)`; I mentioned that right after the code.

Comment: @ecatmur: Wouldn't changing your answer to `class Empty(object):` make it work for both Python 2.2+ through 3.x?

Comment: @martineau but it'd be *less elegant*... oh, fine, I'll change it.  Cheers!

Comment: @ecatmur: +1 _Elegance_ is beholden to the eye. Some even think "Explicit is better than implicit".

Answer (score 1):

Havn't came across any such object, which doesn;t have any attribute.. see below

```
In [74]: class dummy():
   ....:     pass
   ....:

In [75]: d1 = dummy()

In [76]: dir(d1)
Out[76]: ['__doc__', '__module__']

In [77]: len(dir(d1))
Out[77]: 2
```

even None has attributes...

```
In [78]: dir(None)
Out[78]:
['__class__',
 '__delattr__',
 '__doc__',
 '__format__',
 '__getattribute__',
 '__hash__',
 '__init__',
 '__new__',
 '__reduce__',
 '__reduce_ex__',
 '__repr__',
 '__setattr__',
 '__sizeof__',
 '__str__',
 '__subclasshook__']
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes! (or no...)

```
def AMeta(name, bases, dct):
    class NoProp:
        pass
    del NoProp.__doc__
    del NoProp.__module__
    return NoProp

class A:
    __metaclass__ = AMeta

print dir(A), 'len', len(dir(A))

print
print 'but... A.__name__ is', A.__name__
print 'Delete it!'
try:
    del A.__name__
except Exception as e:
    print 'Did not work: ', repr(e)

print
print 'and... A.__dict__ is', A.__dict__
print 'Delete it!'
try:
    del A.__dict__
except Exception as e:
    print 'Did not work: ', repr(e)

print
print 'and... A.__bases__ is', A.__bases__
print 'Delete it!'
try:
    del A.__bases__
except Exception as e:
    print 'Did not work: ', repr(e)

print 
print 'What is the type of A?'
t = type(A)
print t, 'which is a', type(t)

print "All of these will raise an AttributeError:"
print "A.__class__, A.__module__, (and maybe some others which are usually there too...)"
```

Normally, all objects have **some** attributes whatever these are. But when using metaclasses, you can customize the way the class is created, and there you have it.

However, even if `dir` is empty, you can still access `A.__name__`, `A.__dict__`, `A.__bases__`.

This is what the tests I made gave me:

```
[] len 0

but... A.__name__ is NoProp
Delete it!
Did not work:  TypeError('__name__ must be a string object',)

and... A.__dict__ is {}
Delete it!
Did not work:  TypeError('__dict__ must be a dictionary object',)

and... A.__bases__ is ()
Delete it!
Did not work:  TypeError('__bases__ must be a tuple object',)

What is the type of A?
<type 'classobj'> which is a <type 'type'>
All of these will raise an AttributeError:
A.__class__, A.__module__, (and maybe some others which are usually there too...)
```

Comment: so the answer is "no", even if dir(x) returns empty, x still has methods/attributes.

Comment: @PauloScardine You're right, but that `A` class still passes his test. Doesn't it?

Comment: dir(len(1)) isn't the test. It's just visualization of question

Comment: What were you basing your facts on? What `dir` returned... Anyway, I added details, the answer is "no", but can *look* like "yes".

Answer (score 0):

You can create an object without any "public" attributes and methods:

```
class Bare(object):
    pass
```

But this object will have some internal/standard methods and attributes:

```
>>> x = Bare()
>>> dir(x)
['__class__',
 '__delattr__',
 '__doc__',
 '__format__',
 '__getattribute__',
 '__hash__',
 '__init__',
 '__new__',
 '__reduce__',
 '__reduce_ex__',
 '__repr__',
 '__setattr__',
 '__sizeof__',
 '__str__',
 '__subclasshook__']
```

Python has no concept of enforced private methods and attributes, everything is exposed. However, by convention, you should avoid external access to methods and attributes beginning with `_`, these should be reserved for internal use (double underscores for Python internal methods). In practice you can check for an instance without any "public" attributes:

```
>>> filter(lambda a: a[0] != '_', dir(x))
[]

>>> len(filter(lambda a: a[0] != '_', dir(x)))
0
```

Even if you cheat by overriding `__dir__` and `__getattribute__`, the built-in attributes are still there and can be accessed using `__getattribute__` from the parent class (thanks for [martineau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/355230/martineau) to point me this):

```
class FakeEmpty:
    def __dir__(self):
        return []
    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        raise AttributeError("'{0}' object has no attribute '{1}'".format(type(self).__name__, name))

>>> e = FakeEmpty()
>>> object.__getattribute__(e, '__class__')
__main__.Empty
```

So the answer is: not really, but you can almost fake it.

Comment: you are inheriting from object class, the Bare class will have some attributes of object class

Comment: Indeed, you can declare "old style" classes that don't inherit from object, but should you do it in modern Python?

Comment: yes, new style class are very good, but my only point was, even in old style classes, object will have attributes :)