# Is it possible to introspect actual attributes/methods of an object which overrides `__dir__` and `__getattribute__`?

Tags: python, introspection

Some answers from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11536961/python-object-atributes-and-methods/11537394#comment15254706_11537394) bring very silly ways to cripple the ability to access methods and attributes for instances of objects overriding `__dir__` and `__getattribute__`.

The attributes and methods are still there, but are they really inaccessible?

For example, `type(x)` still returns the correct answer even if `x.__class__` raises AttributeError.

Is there any way to access the hidden methods and attributes?

Comment: @martineau: interesting, but how about the instance `__dict__`?

Comment: Since it's a new style class, `object.__getattribute__(x, '__dict__')`

Comment: @martineau: genius! make it an answer so you can collect a few reputation points.

Comment: Naw...just a RTFM kind-of-person. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For instances of a new-style class you could do something like this:

```
object.__getattribute__(instance, '__dict__')
```

I got the idea while reading a section titled [*More attribute access for new-style classes*](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#more-attribute-access-for-new-style-classes) in the documentation, where they suggest doing something like that to avoid infinite recursion in its implementation.